# Virtual Shared Driver Indexing problems

Tags: windows, azure, azure-active-directory, shared-directory, shared-drive

We just virtualized a Windows server in Azure and everything in working fine on Client side, but we are not being able to solve the indexing search problem.

When you have a local drive, Windows can index the path and searches works fine using Windows menu/search box in task bar. But for shared drives it seems to fail.

In Windows Explorer the search pretends to work, but it takes forever to find a file or folder. And sometimes it just won't move anywhere. So it is not an option for users since them are used to search using menu bar.

We have tried to change drive properties in `Right button to Shared Driver > "Allow files on this drive to have contents indexed in addition to file properties`, but it was already enabled.

When we try to disable it, it prompts an error saying that the user doesn't have permission to do it, but it does anyway. And when we try to re-enable, the message prompts again, but it is enabled with no problem at all. But once again, nothing changes and Initial Menu Search just won't work.

Does anyone knows if there is a solution for that?

For me it seems to be an server setup since I see that permission error, but, as far as I know, if the shared driver is already mounted, I can't see a reason why Windows can't index it.

Ps.1: In the shared drive security tab, the System has full permissions.

Ps.2: If there is a solution for this, is that possible to solve it on the Windows server Side so we won't need to access client by client to change it manually?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MmnR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following setting and see.

1.First thing is to check network location is being indexed. open File Explorer right-click on the mapped network drive that you need to index, then select the Properties  and Make sure that, the Allow Files on this Drive to Have Contents Indexed checkbox is selected.
You have already done this step

2.try to check the search options for network drive in file explorer, go to view tab>>click on Options Icon and choose the change folder and search option menu it will open the folder options dialog box and select search tab and make sure first option is not selected

3.check server side Indexing

4.we need to make sure search service needs to be running.
Open services.msc check for the  wndows search service and try to restart the service.

5.Go to Settings on the Windows 10 desktop, then click on Search, followed by Searching Windows scroll down and try to run the indexer troubleshooter

Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/fix-problems-in-windows-search